# Include temporary employees when calculating turnover rates?

Tags: terminology

I'm calculating my organization's 2014 total turnover rate. Are number of our temporary employees separated from the organization because it was the end of their assignment. It doesn't make sense to me to include them in the calculation, because the organization is aware of their tenure from day one. I would understand including temp staff members who leave (vol or involuntary) prior to the end date of their assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I really like [wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnover_%28employment%29) definition of turnover:

> In human resources context, turnover is the act of replacing an employee with a new employee.

In this context, it wouldn't make much sense to include temp employees unless they were temp-to-hire.

Now I would also include a statistic of temp employee turnover, but keep it separated from your total turnover rate. That way the information is there if the people looking at it had some need for that information.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would suggest not counting temps who were intended to leave at a certain time as turnover. However, the person who would know what the company wants is the person who will be using the data. If he wants the temp data too, I can suggest that you provide figures in such a way that permanent employee turnover rates can be calculated separately from temps. One would expect temp rates to be higher, after all one presumes many temps leave for permanent postions somewhere else. That says nothing of how you are doing at retaining employees just that being a temp is not something most people want to be.